# kids smartwatch buying guidelines

Tags: smart-device

The smartwatch market is absolutely saturated. I have no clue how to tell which products and brands are good or bad.

Presumably many of the brands are using the same underlying hardware and just providing their own branding and software.

**Is there a guide anywhere for how to tell what hardware and software platform a given product uses?**

Example of the kind of thing I'm looking for:

- [Which?](https://www.which.co.uk/reviews/smartwatches) tells me which OS these watches use

I am looking for a low cost smart watch for my children (7 & 8) who have been admiring my el-cheapo smart watch. They are too young to have a proper phone. However, I notice that many of the smartwatches even the cheap ones support 2G, GPS and SOS calls.

Basically I'm looking for:

- A heart monitor     (as in a cheap tracker)
- Games
- Ability change watch faces (common but not standard).
- Not too chunky.
- Standalone but multiple devices can sync to (ideally the same) tablet easily (e.g. via wifi)
- Cheap (up to £40)
- Magnetic or USB3 charging.
  (This new fad of removing the strap and plugging the whole watch into a USB socket is terrible)

Nice to have:

- Music player
- Camera
- Not advertised as a phone (so they don't think they have one and won't pester us for a SIM)
  (If it is a phone with GPS tracker and SOS fine)

It seems that if you go down the heart monitor route you get a fitness watch.
Down the games route you tend to get something chunkier and the heart monitor if present is not advertised.

For example from Amazon we have:

- INIUPO Kids Smartwatch for Boys Girls Phone Game Smart Watch for kids Children Music Player Camera Alarm Clock Birthday Gift (Black)
- Smooce Kids Smartwatch Phone, Waterproof Smartwatch for Kids with LBS Tracker SOS Voice Chat and Camera Game for 3-12 Years Old Kids Birthday
- Kids Smart Watch Phone - IP67 Waterproof Smartwatch Boys Girls with Touch Screen 5 Games Camera Alarm SOS Call - Phone Watch Digital Wrist Watch for 3-13

Aside: My requirements are different as I have a smartphone so actually the watch doesn't need anything the phone can do.
But if it was for me I'd also want:

- wifi
- GPS (in case I leave the phone at home)
- A standard OS (e.g. WearOS or Android) - hackable if possible.
- some onboard storage
- volume and track selection musics controls

Comment: The ability to change watch faces is not (yet) standard as I discovered (but I got away with it this xmas). For the specific case of Amazon I found the sellers quick to respond to questions I posted such as "what OS is used?"