# Smartwatch for 10-year-old child

Tags: smartphones, smart-device

I am looking for an advice about choosing a smartwatch for a 10-year-old child.

**Required features:**

- Can make phone calls using only the watch.
- Has a watch, an alarm, a timer and a stopwatch.
- Water-resistant.
- Has an app for the smartphone.

**Optional features:**

- GPS.

**Related:**

- [kids smartwatch buying guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14311/16366) (no answers for this old question)
- [Apple Watch Versus Gizmo :: What Smart Watch To Buy For Your Kids](https://neworleansmom.com/perspectives-in-parenting/apple-watch-versus-gizmo-what-smart-watch-to-buy-for-your-kids/)
- [Verizon GizmoWatch Is An Apple Watch For Kids, Sort Of - SlashGear](https://www.slashgear.com/verizon-lg-gizmowatch-release-date-price-kids-smartwatch-child-20546592)

Answer (score 0):

We ended up buying an **Apple Watch SE GPS + Cellular**. It works well for us so far (we used it heavily for 6 months). In addition to the above features, we found these other features to be very useful:

- Text messaging.
- Weather.
- Location tracking.
- Find my watch functionality to find the misplaced watch.

The only con is that it is more expensive than some other smart watches, due to it having more functionalities.